# PHP/SQL Results based on current time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I would like to be able to do, is have a section on the website that shows a **Whats On Now** and **Whats On Next** panel.

I've created a `MySQL` database with the radio schedule in it. Now I have managed (somehow) to create a basic table showing now and next based upon the current date, which is set as the primary key in the `SQL`, but I need this to react to the current time, which is the column headings. Here's the code so far:

```
 <?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","web3-schedule");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE Date= CURDATE()");
  echo "<b>".date('l\ F jS\ Y ')."</b>";
  echo "</br><b>".date('G:ia')."</b>";
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Now</th>
  <th>Next</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['18'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['19'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

What I need to do is change the `$row` variables so that they are based upon the current system time (hour).

Comment: are you talking about the datatype of the field `Date` in your `schedule` table ?

Comment: [`CURTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime)